# mapael map class doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mapael

The base library is an angular js.

I am trying to draw a map using mapael.js

However, it is not created with errors.

library version : jquery 1.11.3, angular 1.5, jquery.mapael 2.0.0

**error message:**
The map class `map` doesn't exists

html

```
<div id="MapSearchResultPlot" class="div-theme" style="height: 450px; width: 100px; align: center;">
   <div id="ChildMap" class="map">
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var $world = $("#MapSearchResultPlot");
    $world.mapael({
        map: {
           //name: "usa_states",
           name: "world_countries",
           zoom: {
               enabled: true
               ,maxLevel: 10
               ,init: {
                    latitude: 40.717079,
                    longitude: -74.00116,
                    level: 0
                    //level: 10
                }
              },
              defaultPlot: {
                 type: 'circle' //'square','circle'
                 ,size:10
                 ,attrs: {fill: "#ff5454"}
             }
           },
           plots: {
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's maybe too late but I post this because I got this error too.

Your html must look like this:

```
<div class="mapcontainer">
    <div class="map">
        <span>Alternative content for the map</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still very useful. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, you really need to have that inner div with class "map", otherwise it won't render.